# How to move Odoo 9 from one server to another?

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, odoo-9

We have moved Odoo Server one to another local Ubuntu Server. I have backed up our database from the admin dashboard. I have a few questions.

1. Which files should I move to other servers?
2. Do we need install software like OpenERP, PostgreSQL in the new server?
3. Do we need install dependencies such as `wkhtmltopdf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

1. **Backup you Database** to restore it afterwards on your new server. The safest way is to do it within the Odoo Database Manager. If the restoration does not succeed, sometimes this happens, try to copy and restore it by hand with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, or retore it with `psql` and copy your `filestore` to the right destination.
2. **Copy your Complete Instance (Odoo source code)**. This is at least all the Odoo modules you are using in your old server, including base modules and where the Odoo launcher is stored and your custom modules.
3. **Copy your Service and [Configuration File](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/cmdline.html#reference-cmdline-config)**.
4. **Install all the [Odoo dependencies](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html#deb)** and the dependencies of all the modules you are using. These dependencies includes PostgreSQL and Wkhtmltopdf among others.

   **Note:** Sometimes you need to keep the same versions of some dependencies. If something goes wrong make sure you have the same version or a compatible version installed

Answer (score 0):

The information that is supported are the records that you created and the modification you make to the odoo configuration.

The destination server must have all installed software dependencies include modules, odoo-base, wkhtmlpdf
before upload backup.

Hope this help you